# PHP View files deleted with unknown reason

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a very ambiguous problem with php CI project;
An specific file as a view delete in an unknown date and time, maybe twice a day and reason is totally unknown and 100% we have not any unlink or file streams on that.
Is there possible any configurations cause to delete or system restore point in Cpanel? Databases still stay updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was probably due to a shared Linux Server with an specific cron job restoring directories data and replaced every unknown specific period of the time.

By changing host information this problem solves totally.